# Using a combination of config and command line arguments with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack with a large config file. To produce the bundle, I just enter "webpack" in the app folder and everything works fine.

Now I want to still be able to use the config file, but also override the output path on the command line, e.g.

```
>webpack input_path output_path
```

where input_path and output_path are just placeholders here.

Is it possible to use a webpack.config.js AND override parts of this configuration through command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Plz see the documentation on webpack client (CLI)
https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/

//usage with config file. //i.e. webpack.config.js

```
webpack [--config webpack.config.js]
```

//usage without config file:

```
webpack <entry> [<entry>] <output>
```

where entry refers to the entry point of ur app. (Mine is /app/index.js)
output can contain the outputpath and the outputfilename

To give an idea, below is my webpack.config.js :- (for es6)

```
module.exports = {
  entry : ['./app/index.js'], //entrypoint
  output: {
    path: 'D:\\js\\es6\\build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [ //specify objects for each loader
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader' ,
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude:  /node_modules/, //we dont want to transpile the .js on node_modules
        }
      ]
  },
  devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      contentBase: './build',
      inline: true, //allows us to run automatic live code update
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not really - My question was not how I can use the config file XOR the command parameters to produce the bundle. I'd rather like to know if and how I can use a config file AND overwrite some of the content of the config file by command line arguments. Or did I get your answer wrong?

Comment: So, if i understand u correctly, u have ur webpack running (using a webpack.config.js) and still u want to run some other entry-point/output-file without affecting the earlier one. yes, that is possible. Do the below:- (1) npm install webpack --save-dev                                   (2) D:\js\es6\node_modules\webpack\bin>node webpack.js "D:\js\es6\app\recipe.js" "D:\js\es6\build\bundle2.js"

Comment: Yes, that goes into the right direction: I have a config file and just want to overwrite the output field of this config file through command line parameter, while the other entries in the config file still need to be effective. However , I did not exactly get the solution you proposed - can you formulate that in a fully blown answer?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it.